# Android - Animation Issue

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I'm trying to slide a view up from the bottom of the screen to the top and its doing the animation but at the end it goes back to the bottom on the screen. I can't figure out why. Heres the code:

```
public void slideUp() {

    Animation slide = null;
    slide = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -5.0f);

    slide.setDuration(4000);
    SubviewManager.getSelectedRouteView().startAnimation(slide);

    slide.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            SubviewManager.getSelectedRouteView().clearAnimation();

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    SubviewManager.getSelectedRouteView().getWidth(), SubviewManager.getSelectedRouteView().getHeight());
            Log.e("Rules", "Rules " + lp.getRules().toString());
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, 0);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
            SubviewManager.getSelectedRouteView().setLayoutParams(lp);

        }

    });
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/selected_route_layout"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/time_label"
            android:textColor="#1D1C18"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/eta_label"
            android:textColor="#7EC82F"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/time_label"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/time_label"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/time_label" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/time_label"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/route_breakdown"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/via_label"
            android:textColor="#BDBDBD"
            android:layout_below="@+id/route_breakdown"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:id="@+id/arrow_up"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:src="@drawable/transit_symbol_up_arrow"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Heres the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/selected_route_layout"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/time_label"
            android:textColor="#1D1C18"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/eta_label"
            android:textColor="#7EC82F"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/time_label"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/time_label"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/time_label" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/time_label"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/route_breakdown"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/via_label"
            android:textColor="#BDBDBD"
            android:layout_below="@+id/route_breakdown"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:id="@+id/arrow_up"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:src="@drawable/transit_symbol_up_arrow"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you're using old tools for animation and you've just described one of its drawbacks. Consider using Animator and changing your view's TranslationX and TranslationY properties.

One of possible examples:

```
yourView.animate().translationY(newY).setDuration(duration).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // your onAnimationEnd actions
    }
}).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting slide.setFillAfter(true)

If fillAfter is true, the transformation that this animation performed will persist when it is finished.

Or move to property animations if possible (nineoldandroids for back support)
It will be much easier then.

Comment: I tried this and nothing happened. Still did the same thing. What do you mean by using property animiation? using the anim xml files?

Comment: What u are using is the old view animation implementation. From SDK 13+ thres an animation "platform" called property animations using the Animator class and actually animating an object's property.in your case the translationY and translationY  properties.  Have a look here for more info.   http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.htmloper.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html