# TranslateAnimation from middle to Top Left without cutting off view

Tags: android, android-animation, translate-animation

I have a parent container called `mContainer` and a child view called `mChildImageView`. The `ImageView` is positioned in the middle of the container and I am trying to translate the `ImageView` to the top left without cutting off the `ImageView`.

What I would like is to translate the top most point of the `ImageView` to the top left part of `mContainer`, this way it would make the `ImageView` cut off.

This is the following code I am using, as you can see I am using Absolute coordinates, I would like to make it more dynamic how can I accomplish this?

```
TranslateAnimation a = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.ABSOLUTE,             // Specifies X-Type interpretation, ABSOLUTE, RELATIVE_TO_SELF, RELATIVE_TO_PARENT
            0.0f,                           // Change in x coordinate at start of animation, can be absolute or percentage if RELATIVE
            Animation.ABSOLUTE,
            -30,                            // Change in x coordinate at end of animation, can be absolute or percentage if RELATIVE
            Animation.ABSOLUTE,             // Specifies Y-Type interpretation, ABSOLUTE, RELATIVE_TO_SELF, RELATIVE_TO_PARENT
            0.0f,                           // Change in y coordinate at start of animation, can be absolute or percentage if RELATIVE
            Animation.ABSOLUTE,
            30                              // Change in y coordinate at end of animation, can be absolute or percentage if RELATIVE
    );

mChildImageView.setAnimation(a);
mChildImageView.animate();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change TranslationX or/and TranslationY parameters of a view with relation to its parent, I highly recommend you to use Animators instead of Animations as they have some drawbacks (for example: [Android - Animation Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33262199/5247331)).

Possible variant:

```
mChildImageView.animate().translationX(newTranslationX).translationY(newTranslationY).setDuration(duration).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out so to get it to move to the top left we can do the following

```
TranslateAnimation a = new TranslateAnimation(
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,            
        0.0f,                          
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,
        -20.0f,      // Translate to left - This is arbitrary enter your own value             
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,           
        0.0f,                           
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,
        -15.0f       // Translate up - This is arbitrary enter your own value                         
);

mChildImageView.setAnimation(a);
mChildImageView.animate();
```

RELATIVE_TO_PARENT uses percentages so 0.0f to 1.0f